# Bloc: Porque o sink não aciona minha função Stream?

Tags: flutter

Estou com um problema, que creio que seja de entendimento do conceito no uso de bloc.
Entendi que um sink com um stream vinculado sempre vai acionar o stream caso seja feito um add( "alguma informacao" );

Mas, não está acontecendo neste caso. Por quê?

```
class CreateSuggestionsBloc extends BlocBase {
  final CreateSuggestionsRepository repo;
  final String word;

  var blocPage1 = CreateSuggestionsModule.to.getBloc<CreateSuggestionsBlocStep1>();
  var blocPage2 = CreateSuggestionsModule.to.getBloc<CreateSuggestionsBlocStep2>();
  var blocPage3 = CreateSuggestionsModule.to.getBloc<CreateSuggestionsBlocStep3>();

  CreateSuggestionsBloc(this.repo,{this.word}){ 
     responseOut = dataSuggestion.switchMap(observableSuggestionPost); 
  }

  String email;
  String password;

  int _data1;
  int _data2;
  int _data3;

  var dataSuggestion = BehaviorSubject<Suggestion>();

  Suggestion get dataValue => dataSuggestion.value;
  Stream<int> responseOut;
  Sink<Suggestion> get dataIn => dataSuggestion.sink;

  void register( {item, data} ){
    if ( item == 1 ){
      _data1 = data;
    } else if ( item == 2 ){
      _data2 = data;
    } else if ( item == 3 ){
      _data3 = data;
    }
  }

  void saveall(){
    print( 'blocPage.word = [' + this.word + ']' );
    print( 'blocPage1.Data = ' + blocPage1.data.toString() );
    print( 'blocPage2.Data = ' + blocPage2.data.toString() );
    print( 'blocPage3.Data = ' + blocPage3.data.toString() );
    dataIn.add( new Suggestion( userId: '0',
           name: blocPage1.data.toString(),
           description: blocPage3.data.toString(),           
           languageId: blocPage2.data.toString() ) );    
    print( 'Save all data' );
  }

  Stream<int> observableSuggestionPost(Suggestion data) async* {
    yield 0;
    try{
    //TODO: Implements repository save data
    var response = await repo.createSuggestions(data.toJson());
    yield 1;
    }catch(e){
      throw e;
    }
  }


  @override
  void dispose() {
    dataSuggestion.close();
    super.dispose();
  }

}
```

Neste trecho não aciona observableSuggestionPost, o que posso estar esquecendo.

```
dataIn.add( new Suggestion( userId: '0',
           name: blocPage1.data.toString(),
           description: blocPage3.data.toString(),           
           languageId: blocPage2.data.toString() ) );
```

O trecho acima deveria acionar o trecho a seguir, mas, isso não ocorre. Por quê?

```
Stream<int> observableSuggestionPost(Suggestion data) async* {
yield 0;
try{
//TODO: Implements repository save data
var response = await repo.createSuggestions(data.toJson());
yield 1;
}catch(e){
  throw e;
}}
```

Comment: onde você está subscrito para ouvir a novos eventos dessa stream?

Comment: vc está dando o "observe" com a função `switchMap` ja tentou com o `listen`? (não lembro se é o `listen` ou o `doOnListen`)

Comment: @mrocigno não tentei com listen. Vou estudar sobre isso. Já é um caminho :) Provisoriamente eu to chamando a função na criação da page, mas, vou analisar essa possibilidade. Valeu!